# How to fix Error inflating class Android.support.v7.widget.CardView

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview

I know this question has been asked many times but non of them solved my issues.  I am trying to use CardView inside RecyclerView but no luck so far.
here is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.Android.com/apk/res-auto"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center"
  card_view:cardCornerRadius="4dp"
  card_view:cardBackgroundColor="#AA66CC"
  card_view:cardElevation="10dp"
  android:id="@+id/cv">

<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="center">

  <TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:id="@+id/list_item"
    android:text="asdasd asdasd tt"
    />
</RelativeLayout>

</Android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

and here is my adapter:

```
public class ApprovalListAdapter  extends Adapter<ApprovalListAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private String[] dataSource;
private Context mContext;
public ApprovalListAdapter(String[] dataArgs, Context context){
    dataSource = dataArgs;
    mContext = context;

}
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // create a new view
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.approval_list_row, parent, false);

    ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return viewHolder;


}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView.setText(dataSource[position]);
}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSource.length;
}

public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
    protected TextView textView;
    protected CardView cv;
    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        cv = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
        textView =  (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.list_item);

    }
  }
}
```

I've also added the required dependencies

```
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
  compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
  compile project(":volley")
}
```

i.e CardView works perfectly fine when its not in the RecyclerView.

Comment: not works means what the exact problem you getting?

Comment: `android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Android.support.v7.widget.CardView` @pavan

Comment: is it showing nothing or shows atleast one item

Comment: It crushes the app @pavan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to have a case error, the cardview tag start by a lowercase.
In your xml, replace:

`<Android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
</Android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`

with:

`<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
...
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>`

Comment: Thanks, that fixed my problem!!

Comment: Thanks! I typed `cardview` instead of `CardView` and got the problem too..